# Gradle multiproject dependency with spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, gradle-plugin

I have spring boot project structure like below:

```
client-stp-grid-publisher:
+---.build.gradle
+---.client-stp-grid-publisher-acceptance
|   +---build.gradle
+---.client-stp-grid-publisher-core
|   +---build.gradle
```

client-stp-grid-publisher-acceptance needs executable jar created by `task ':client-stp-grid-publisher-core:bootRepackage'` to start process
before running acceptance tests to test complete flow. So I am running `bootRepackage task` of core project and then copy over the executable jar
to `acceptance-test project build/tmp directory`.

Also acceptance tests are using some classes from project `':client-stp-grid-publisher-core'`.

Since `task ':client-stp-grid-publisher-core:bootRepackage'` get executed first before `task ':client-stp-grid-publisher-acceptance:test'`
some of tests are failing which use classes from core project.

If I restrict the core project build to `distZip task` then all test under acceptance project get passed.

Error I am getting while running acceptance-test with bootRepackage:

```
failure message="java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/markets/efx/client/stp/builder/GridDealsObjectBuilder;" 
type="java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError">java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/markets/efx/client/stp/builder/GridDealsObjectBuilder
```

But my requirement needs bootRepackage so that I can run executable jar from acceptance test project.

It will be really helpful if I can get suggestions on how to resolve the issue or some workaround to achieve the requirement?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to copy jars manually.

settings.gradle:

```
include 'client-stp-grid-publisher'
include 'client-stp-grid-publisher-acceptance'
include 'client-stp-grid-publisher-core'
```

build.gradle for 'client-stp-grid-publisher-acceptance'

```
...
dependencies {
    compile project(":client-stp-grid-publisher-core")
    ...
```

I suggest reading up on setting up a multi module project using gradle:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/

Comment: These I already have in the project as you mentioned. Issue is core project task bootRepackage creates fat executable jar. So ideally bootRepackage should run before acceptance-test test cases run. But in that case test cases will get failed by  NoClassDefFoundError.